# How to disable selected columns in a datagrid in flex for selected rows?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

Is there any way to disable a few columns for a particular row in flex datagrid?

I have a datagrid with about 10 or more columns, say for example a few column names are: `Item Id`, `Item Name`, `Item Status` and `VerifiedState`. Initially I want the column `Verified State` to be disabled.

Now When the value of the column, `Item Status` is `Review Passed`  for a particular row, I want the column `VerifiedState` to be enabled and editable. Is that possible in Flex datagrid.

If so, how can I achieve it.

Comment: you want to disable column or row? title says row but the third para in your question says column

Comment: I want to disable selected columns in selected rows.. 
sorry about the confusion in the question. I'll change it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do an ItemRenderer for the `VerifiedState` column, that won't show anything unless `Item Status` is `Review Passed`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree use ItemRenderers, for any of the columns you want to disable.  Then in your override of 'set data' just check if the row is in the correct state and add PropertyChange listeners to data obj (so when the object enters the correct state you can enable the column).